# localStorage.setItem does not want to store JWT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, backend

I have an async function for a login call in a controller file, it looks something like this:

```js
login: async(req, res) => {
        try {
            const {email, password} = req.body
            const user = await Users.findOne({email})
            if(!user) return res.status(400).json({msg: "This email does not exist."})

            const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
            if(!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({msg: "Incorrect password. Please try again."})

            console.log(user)

            const payload = {id: user._id, name: user.name}
            const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: "7d"})
            
            res.cookie('token', token, {
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 7*24*60*60*1000 //7 days
            })

            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));

            res.json({msg: "Login successful", token})
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
        }
```

I'm trying to store the JWT that's been generated into localStorage for retrieval on subsequent API calls. I've gotten it so that I can see that the cookie that's been created is there every time I go to my local dev server.

Currently, upon login, this throws a ReferenceError and I'm unsure why.

Error: return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
^

ReferenceError: err is not defined

What's the proper way of putting a generated token into localStorage?

Comment: *What* throws a reference error? Which line? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Edited with error message

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear? `err` isn't defined. Did you mean `error` instead?

Comment: Seems I haven't had enough coffee yet today

Comment: Unrelated answer but... I hope it is not your real code... and you use a real oauth2 / oidc identity prodvider...

Comment: bro how did you solve this?i have same error with no error in console